# Object has no method 'indexOf'

Tags: javascript, indexof

I have the following function (taken from [Elevation Service @ Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation))  which output for example `63.00425720214844` when I click somewhere on the map I have created with [Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial):

```
function getElevation(event) {
    var locations = [];
    var clickedLocation = event.latLng;
    locations.push(clickedLocation);

    var positionalRequest = {
        'locations': locations
    }

    elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function(results, status) {
        if(status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
            var s = results[0].elevation
            if(results[0]) {
                alert(s.substring(0, s.indexOf('.') - 1));
            } else {
                alert('Inget resultat hittades');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Det gick inte att hitta höjdskillnaden på grund av följande: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

I want to remove everything after the dot including the dot, for example remove `.00425720214844` from `63.00425720214844` but when I click somewhere on the map, I'm getting this error message in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Object 63.00425720214844 has no method 'indexOf'`.

What have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know exactly with it prints `63.00425720214844`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265879/what-does-it-mean-when-an-object-has-no-method-in-javascript

Comment: I have already readed that question and also the answers.

Comment: by the way, you might consider moving the s = ... assignment down by 1 line, otherwise you're checking for results[0] after you've already accessed it.

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof s)` or `console.dir(s)` tell you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do a javascript `parseInt(63.00425720214844)` to get 63.

Comment: Many thanks - it worked! :D I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 7):

The variable `s` doesn't contain a string.

You can turn it into a string using:

```
s = s.toString();
```

If it's a number, you can just use numeric functions instead:

```
alert(Math.floor(s));
```

Comment: Thanks but Marc's answer was so much simpler :)

Comment: If it's a number, you can also use `s.toFixed(0)`.

Comment: @ErikEdgren: Simpler in what way? Because `parseInt` is two characters less than `Math.floor`...?

Comment: @Guffa: Because it's only one word :) `Math.floor` is very simple too though

Comment: @ErikEdgren: Actually `Math.floor(s)` is simpler than `parseInt(s.toString())`, which is what it really should read...